# Typesetting pinyin finals

Tags: accents, cjk

With the package `\pinyin`, it is possible to write pinyin using commands such as `\bu4`. This package produces much better tone marks than are provided by `\'`, `\v`, etc.

The package `\pinyin` includes all of the pinyin for full words, as well as `\a` and `\o` (because by themselves these can be words), however, I need to typeset the remaining finals individually:

> ē
>   é
>   ě
>   è
>   ī
>   í
>   ǐ
>   ì
>   ū
>   ú
>   ǔ
>   ù
>   ǖ
>   ǘ
>   ǚ
>   ǜ

It is rare for these to appear on their own, hence, I have not been able to locate any commands which will print them, provided by the `pinyin` package, so I think the authors left that out.

I have found a copy of the source code on [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/CJK/cjk-4.8.2/texinput/pinyin.sty), however, it does not appear to be using LaTeX code to define things. I believe somewhere in this code much of the answer, but it is filled with these strange `@` and `#`'s:

```
\def\py@@#1#2#3#4{
  \py@kern{#2}#1
  \ifcase #4
    \or\py@macron #1{.3}\or\py@acute #1\or\py@hacek #1\or\py@grave #1\or #1
  \fi
  \py@kern #1{#3}}

\def\py@a{\py@@ a}
\def\py@A{\py@@ A}

\def\py@e{\py@@ e}
\def\py@E{\py@@ E}

\def\py@i#1#2#3{
  \py@kern{#1}i
  \ifcase #3
    \or\py@macron\i{.3}\or\py@acute\i\or\py@hacek\i\or\py@grave\i\or i
  \fi
  \py@kern i{#2}}
\def\py@I{\py@@ I}

\def\py@o{\py@@ o}
\def\py@O{\py@@ O}

\def\py@u{\py@@ u}
\def\py@U{\py@@ U}
```

How can I replicate the results of the `pinyin` package, but only displaying the finals (ending vowels) on their own?

Update: Just to clarify, I don't need all of the finals (i.e. -ue, -ing), as I can typeset those with a combination of letters.

Comment: \def\LOL@code_with#! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## 1. Quick solution

First, let me answer your question in short: feel free to use `\v{e}`, `\'\i` and `\={\"u}` to typeset ě, í and ǖ. You don't need `pinyin` package for this. And `pinyin` package itself is just a shortening for these accents.

## 2. A better implementation

Honestly, `pinyin` package on CTAN is not at all well implemented. It is dangerous to redefine, for example, `\mu` as pinyin since it is a Greek letter!

Here is a much better implementation of pinyin in Chinese, by 蒋 (ID: pointer) from [CTeX forum](http://bbs.ctex.org/viewthread.php?tid=40039), a Chinese TeX community:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}% for Chinese, but not necessary for Pinyin

% Definitions of Pinyin
\makeatletter
\def\py@yunpriv#1{%
  \if a#1 10\else
  \if o#1 9\else
  \if e#1 8\else
  \if i#1 7\else
  \if u#1 6\else
  \if v#1 5\else
  \if A#1 4\else
  \if O#1 3\else
  \if E#1 2\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi0
}

\def\py@init{%
  \edef\py@befirst{}%
  \edef\py@char{}\edef\py@tuneletter{}%
  \def\py@last{}%
  \def\py@tune{5}%
}

% Usage:
% \pinyin{Hao3hao3\ xue2xi2} （好好学习）
\def\pinyin#1{%
  \edef\py@postscan{#1}%
  \py@init
  % scan
  \loop
  \edef\py@char{\expandafter\@car\py@postscan\@nil}%
  \edef\py@postscan{\expandafter\@cdr\py@postscan\@nil}%
  \ifnum 0 < 0\py@char
    \edef\py@tune{\py@char}%
    \py@first \py@tuneat\py@tuneletter\py@tune \py@last\kern -4sp\kern 4sp{}\py@init
  \else
    \ifnum\py@yunpriv\py@char > \py@yunpriv\py@tuneletter
      \edef\py@tuneletter{\py@char}\edef\py@first{\py@befirst}\def\py@last{}%
    \else
      \edef\py@last{\py@last\if v\py@char\"u\else\py@char\fi}%
    \fi
    \edef\py@befirst{\py@befirst\if v\py@char\"u\else\py@char\fi}%
  \fi
  \ifx\py@postscan\@empty\else
  \repeat
}

\let\py@macron \=
\let\py@acute \'
\let\py@hacek \v
\let\py@grave \`

%% \py@tuneat{Letter}{tune}
\def\py@tuneat#1#2{%
  \if v#1%
    \py@tune@v #2%
  \else
  \if i#1%
    \py@tune@i #2%
  \else
    \ifcase#2%
      \or\py@macron #1\or\py@acute #1\or\py@hacek #1\or\py@grave #1\else #1%
    \fi
  \fi\fi
}

\def\py@tune@v#1{{%
    \dimen@ii 1ex%
    \fontdimen5\font 1.1ex%
    \rlap{\"u}%
    \fontdimen5\font .6ex%
    \ifcase#1%
      \or\py@macron u\or\py@acute u\or\py@hacek u\or\py@grave u\else u%
    \fi
    \fontdimen5\font\dimen@ii
  }}

\def\py@tune@i#1{%
  \ifcase#1
    \or\py@macron \i\or\py@acute \i\or\py@hacek \i\or\py@grave \i\else i%
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
% End of pinyin

\begin{document}

女人 \pinyin{nv3ren2}

木头 \pinyin{mu4tou5} --- $\mu$ % no conflicts

韵母 \pinyin{a1\ i3\ u4\ v2}

啊\pinyin{A1} 哦\pinyin{O4} 恶心吧\pinyin{E3xin1\ ba5}

西安\pinyin{Xi1'an1}

好好学习\pinyin{Hao3hao3\ xue2xi2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## 3. My final advice

Nowadays, we sugguest XeTeX with `xeCJK` for CJK typesetting. XeTeX is a Unicode TeX engine, then you can use ě, í and ǖ in the source code directly, with help of a good GUI input pad. The example above can be changed to:

```
% XeLaTeX needed
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\begin{document}
女人 nǚrén

木头 mùtou --- $\mu$

韵母 ā ǐ ù ǘ
\end{document}
```

Don't use pdfLaTeX or `latex` with CJK to compile this. Since some of the vowels are handled by `CJK` but the fonts are full-width (badly designed), the result may be strange without XeTeX. Of course, if you don't need CJK ideograms, you can use `inputenc` package for the pinyin vowels.

## 4. A new `xpinyin` package is available

Qing Lee (李清) wrote a new [`xpinyin` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpinyin) to typesetting pinyin semi-automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{xpinyin}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
\xpinyin*{汉语拼音示例}

\pinyin{nv3hai2zi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some Chinese fonts need to be installed in your OS to compile the examples. I'm sorry. If you use windows, I think everything should be OK.

Comment: For your solution no.2, is the pinyin implementation by 蒋 currently included as part of any packages?

Comment: @LianTzeLim: No. It is a good implementation and I like it. But I guess I have no right to post his code to CTAN before asking him. BTW, there're still some small problems with his solution in different fonts.

Comment: All of your solutions worked well. I'll look into installing XeTeX. My document already has the marks in place just like you wrote in part 3; this will save me lots of trouble in trying to convert it.

Comment: I am using your method no. 2. and it works very well, except with capital letters. If pinyin code starts with a capital letter, compiling results in an error:
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    \iterate ...r \edef \py@tune {\py@char }\py@first
    \py@tuneat \py@tuneletter ...
Otherwise, if the capital letter is not at the beginning of the code, no error occurs but the output is wrong: e.g. `\pinyin{Wang2\ A1ma}` turns into `WángW̄ A`. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @AndreasT: I fixed the problem for the usual cases. It won't work for wrong pinyins like `W̄`.

Comment: @LeoLiu: Is it true that `xpinyin` only works with simplified Chinese?

Comment: @KevinC: No. We extract the readings from Unihan database.

Comment: +1: Very helpful. Do you have experience with the xpinyin package, is it robust?

Answer (score 5):

Well I have absolutly no knowledge of cjk-scripts and I have no idea what you mean by "finals" etc. But looking at the code I would say to get something similar to `\bu4` you should do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pinyin}

\begin{document}

\bu4 % defined with \py@DRC{\bu}{b\py@ ub{}#1} line 383

\makeatletter
\py@DRC{\be}{b\py@ eb{}#1} %use e instead of u
\makeatother 
\be4
\end{document}
```

Btw: The code of pinyin is normal tex. In a sty like this all the `@` are normal letters like p or q and can be used in command names. The #1 are for arguments of commands.