# Pinyin with pdfLaTeX: Problem with spacings

Tags: spacing, pdftex, cjk

I want to write a document in english and some words in chinese using pdfLaTeX.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
nǔrén\v{a}amùtūou 
\end{document}
```

This shows up as in the image below:

[image]

As you can see after the `ǔ` or the `ū` LaTeX puts automatically a free space even if it's not written in the code, but not after `\v{a}`.

1) Why happens this?

2) How can I avoid this problem? (As you can imagine its not easy to make the change every time)

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

`ctex` package loads `CJKutf8` package with pdfLaTeX. `CJKutf8` package loads `inputenc` with `utf8` option. However, unicode characters like `ǔ` is not defined in `utf8.def`, so `CJK` package treats these characters as CJK wide symbols, using a CJK font. That's the problem.

To fix the problem, you can define these unicode characters yourself:

```
% pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ǚ}{\v{\"u}} % or: \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01DA}{\v{\"u}}
\newunicodechar{ū}{\={u}}
\newunicodechar{ǎ}{\v{a}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary for \v{\"u}

\begin{document}
女人nǚrén

奶奶nǎinai

秃头tūtóu
\end{document}
```

A better solution is to use XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. It's much easier to deal with unicode characters in XeTeX.

```
% XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\begin{document}
女人nǚrén

奶奶nǎinai

秃头tūtóu
\end{document}
```

See also [`xpinyin`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpinyin) package to input pinyin easier.

Related question:

- [Typesetting pinyin finals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35051/typesetting-pinyin-finals)
- [Convert numbered pinyin to pinyin with tone marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125030/convert-numbered-pinyin-to-pinyin-with-tone-marks)