# Pinyin seems to be misunderstood as control sequence

Tags: cjk

I need to use some Chinese characters with pinyin transcriptions in a paper. I have found the CJK package, which includes a pinyin package, and everything seemed to work well. Suddenly it stopped working, and it seems as the pinyin command `\long3` is being interpreted as a control sequence `\long`.

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJK} %Chinese characters
\usepackage{pinyin}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
野草莓運動, \Ye3 \cao3\mei2 \yun4\dong4
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```

Everything works well, until I want to use a character that in pinyin is transcribed as \long3:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJK} %Chinese characters
\usepackage{pinyin}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
壟 \long3
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! You can't use a prefix with `the character 3'.
[...]
I'll pretend you didn't say \long or \outer or \global or \protected.
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: Do not use `pinyin` package. It is poor designed. There are better implementations for pinyin: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35121/2674

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the documentation for `pinyin` (`texdoc pinyin`) says

> use `\Long` and `\LONG` instead of `\long` and `\Long` (which you would
>   expect): `\long` is a very important internal TeX command. Many packages
>   would fail if we redefined `\long`.

Thus you need to use `\Long` here.