# using pinyin package with xelatex

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk, pinyin

I am trying to use the `pinyin` package for glossing Chinese text. There are two problems:

- First, it complains about `\Xi`and `\Pi` allready being defined and
- second the dash about the `a` and the `e` is not set.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}                          
\usepackage{xeCJK}
  \setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{pinyin}

\begin{document}

很 快 *(的) 车 \\
\hen3 \kuai4 *(de) \che1 \\
very fast attr car\\

他 跑 *(得) 很 快。 \\
\Ta1 \pao3 *(de) \hen3 \kuai4. \\
he run deg very fast \\

\end{document}
```

This is what would be correct output:

[image]

Comment: This might be a place to start: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35121/42880.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Thank you very much! The link in the comment to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35121/42880 helped with the answer. Of course typing unicode in directly would be the best solution, but one would break ones fingers and we have everyting in pinyin already. So here is the solution using the `gb4e`package for glossing:

```
\documentclass{book}                          


\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}


\usepackage{xpinyin}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\let\eachwordtwo=\pinyin

\begin{document}

\glll  很 快 *(的) 车 \\
       hen3 kuai4 *(de) che1 \\
       very fast attr car\\


\glll 他 跑 *(得) 很 快。 \\
      Ta1 pao3 *(de) hen3 kuai4. \\
      he run deg very fast \\


\glll 他 很 快 *(地) 跑。 \\
      Ta1 hen3 kuai4 *(de) pao3. \\
      he very fast adv run \\


\end{document}
```

By using `\let\eachwordtwo=\pinyin` the call to `pinyin` is wrapped around every word in the glossing and we get what we want. readable and nice. The only open issue is that `pinyin` adds space before the dot, e.g. after `kuai4` but this can be fixed, I hope.