# Removing space before dots produced by pinyin command

Tags: xpinyin

I use pinyin in glosses and found a way to convert it automatically ([using pinyin package with xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257220/using-pinyin-package-with-xelatex)). However, the call to `pinyin` adds space before a dot. The following code produces `kuài .` rather than `kuài.`. Is there a way to fix this? The manual is in Chinese and I do not understand the code of the `xpinyin`package.

```
\documentclass{book}                          


\usepackage{xpinyin}

\begin{document}

\pinyin{kuai4.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works if you put the dot outside the argument: `\pinyin{kuai4}.` (But as I don't know pinyin I have no idea if this is senseful).

Comment: That would not work since it is automatically included in the call to pinyin in this glossing environment described in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what other consequence this can have, but the space is set at the start with (something equivalent to)

```
\xpinyinsetup{pysep={ }}
```

so you can countermand it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpinyin}

\xpinyinsetup{pysep={}}

\begin{document}

\pinyin{kuai4.}

\end{document}
```

You can also do it locally with

```
\pinyin[pysep={}]{kuai4.}
```

[image]